# Compare multiple columns that are separated, highlighting the Lowest value

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to set up conditional formatting on multiple columns to compare multiple prices and highlight the lowest value.

On the example sheet below. Row 2, the formula would compare the costs in B2, E2, and H2. H2 would be highlighted as the lowest cost.

I was able to do this by using the MIN Formula in column K and then using conditional formation to match the value of B, E, and H to that value, as seen in the example.

Is this possible to do within conditional format only or do the columns need to be next to each other to achieve this?

See the example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PfTCO-nFhaofxdn13KtHurGnXBHin-NEjaMsRMC4_40/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for any help!

-James

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a personalized formula like:

> =Min($b2,$e2,$h2)=b2

If you just want it to apply all B2:B, E2:E,HE:E ranges this conditionl formatting you can add:

> =And(B2<>"",Min($b2,$e2,$h2)=b2)

I've tried it in a copy of your sheet in the spreadsheet you shared ;)